# Trying to add a section at indexPath.row swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Having a little problem with tableviews. I want to add a section to the tableview without messing with the content of the other data in the table. I want to add (cell3, thiscell) at the 4th indexpath.row. What i have is a section on the storyboard which is one cell that i want to add at the 4th index path without messing with all the other information. How would i use the insert section function? or is there any other way to do it?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    if indexPath.section == 0 && cell1 == true{
        let cellIdentifier = "cell1"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = "cell1"
        cell.subNameLabel.text = ""
        return cell
    } else  if indexPath.section == 2 && vally == true{
        let cellIdentifier = "cell2"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Smiles"
        cell.subNameLabel.text = ""
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cellIdentifier = "cell3"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! thisCell
        print("add this after indexpath 2")
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cellIdentifier = "SubCategoryTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
        cell.loading.hidden = false
        cell.loading.startAnimating()
        cell.nameLabel.text = subCat[indexPath.row].subCategoryName
        cell.subNameLabel.text = subCat[indexPath.row].subCategoryDesc
        return cell
    }
    let cell2: SubCategoryTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubCategoryTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTableViewCell
    cell2.userInteractionEnabled = false
    return cell2
}
```

So if there is 10 items in section one when it reach indexpath.row 4 it should insert another section then continue with the other items from section one.

Comment: It makes no sense to insert a section into the middle of another section. At least not without splitting the data into two sections and then inserting the new section between the two sections.

Comment: I find headers and sections a bit of a pain in the butt in a table view, so personally I just treat them as a different type of cell. You could do likewise if it fits with what you want to do. So if your index is 5 then you could use a cell of type section instead of a cell of type content etc. Doing this approach however makes managing the table more complex.